# keep getting error in this line of code: Application.ActiveSheet.Name

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks to some excellent help I received earlier from here, I have been using my new invoicing spreadsheet all evening. Practicing so that I can take it live. It has been working perfectly. Telling me when I have a duplicate and that I should rename sheet, then allow me to re-name and re-save. I have protected a template and copied and then unprotected the worksheet for the user to input too. They do this using a command new invoice. Trying to ensure this works, I have added a new invoice from the "newsheet" that was added to be input to, and attempted to create a duplicate.  It has since kept throwing an error message at me 1004, that name is already taken, try a different one. When i look at the error it is the **'Application.ActiveSheet.Name = VBA.Left(Range("c10") & "-" & Range("a12"), 31)'** line that is throwing the error. I have tried several other statements, but it still is not working correctly. Can anyone help me understand what is wrong with my code line, and is there a better way to write this?

```
'''Set Target = Range("c10")
If Target = "" Then Exit Sub

Application.ActiveSheet.Name = VBA.Left(Range("c10") & "-" & Range("a12"), 31)

Dim Ws As Worksheet, EvalRange As Range
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("c10")) Is Nothing Then
        Set EvalRange = Range(Target.Address)
End If


Set EvalRange = Range("C10")

If Intersect(Target, EvalRange) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
For Each Ws In Worksheets
For Each Cell In EvalRange
With Ws
If .Name <> Target.Parent.Name Then
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets(.Name).Range("C10"), Target.Value) > 0 Then
MsgBox Target.Value & " already exists on the sheet named " & .Name & ".", _
16, "No duplicates allowed in " & EvalRange.Address(0, 0) & "."
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit For
End If
End If
End With
Next
Next Ws

For Each Ws In Worksheets
If Ws.Name <> Target.Parent.Name Then
If Ws.Range(Target.Address) = EvalRange Then
MsgBox Target.Value & " already exists on the sheet named " & Ws.Name & ".", _
16, "No duplicates allowed in " & EvalRange.Address(0, 0) & "."
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.EnableEvents = True
GoTo nextws
End If
End If
nextws:
Next Ws

ActiveSheet.CommandButton4.BackColor = &H8080FF '''
```

Comment: So, it's having a problem with a line that says "set the tab name to whatever is in C10".  It *sounds* like you already have a tab with that name, but without seeing the spreadsheet it's hard to tell.

Comment: Hi there, yes i do have a tab name with the value (created on purpose because we have to generate our own invoice number, but it can't be a duplicate. After testing it all evening, it has been working perfectly. Until i tried to input a new invoice from the new sheet instead of the master. (the command function button is copied across with the new sheet) this will be one of the things that i am sure users will do instead of going back to template.

Comment: Is this code part of an event handler and is it in a worksheet code module?  If Yes then note that the default worksheet scope for `Range()` when the code is in a worksheet module is not ActiveSheet but the sheet corresponding to the code module.  Try being more explicit about your `Range()` calls by always prefixing them with a worksheet reference.

Comment: Hi, i have tried to attach a photo, but I am not sure what has happened to it. I have written this in a module.

Comment: I have tried to change this to several things, but i am new to VBA and just can't work out how to reference this cell in the module, things I have tried i.e Sheets.Add.Name = Range("A1"). I understand what you are telling me, that every sheet in the module has a code, but I am unable to reference it properly across any sheet that might be copied pressing the 'new invoice command' Thank you for your help up to now. I do appreciate it.

Comment: Lots of code there but most of it is not relevant since the error happens in the second line - what exactly happens *before* that?

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Worksheets("Activesheet").Copy before:=Sheets("Master")
ActiveSheet.Name = "NewSheet"
Dim Ws As Worksheet

   Set Ws = Worksheets("NewSheet")

   Ws.Unprotect Password:="password"
   
   
  ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.BackColor = &H8080FF
   
   
End Sub

Comment: This is what happens before that command, and is working beautifully. The whole spreadsheet is working beautifully, its only when a user would add a new invoice from the sheet that they have just input to, instead of going back to the protected ActiveSheet that this error is occuring. (I am trying to anticipate user errors before they happen)

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no clue what's going on, but when I see your error:

```
Application.ActiveSheet.Name = VBA.Left(Range("c10") & "-" & Range("a12"), 31)
```

I see that you are accessing something and modifying it at the same time, to I would opt for this "solution":

```
Dim temp as String
temp = VBA.Left(Range("c10") & "-" & Range("a12"), 31)
Application.ActiveSheet.Name = temp
```

Comment: Thank you. I have inserted the above code, but it is still throwing error. Have I missed something out. Think I have been looking at this too long. Error is Runtime Error '424' object required. This is what it look like with this part of the code inserted.

Comment: Set Target = Range("c10")
If Target = "" Then Exit Sub


Dim temp As String
temp = Application.ActiveSheet.Name
VBA.Left(Range("c10") & "-" & Range("a12"), 31) = tempDim
Dim Ws As Worksheet, EvalRange As Range

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("c10")) Is Nothing Then
        Set EvalRange = Range(Target.Address)
End If

Comment: @Narkyknickers: I'm sorry, I had put the lines in the wrong order, now it's correct.

Comment: Hi @Dominique. Thank you so much for your input. The last line is still throwing an error, i am putting this code into the module sheet, on the 'activesheet' template (which cannot be entered onto, you have to select new invoice). This works and creates a worksheet which i have now named 'NewSheet' this code does work. But not if the user goes out of order and only requests the 'new invoice' from the 'NewSheet' tab. My code works perfectly if I go in the order I know I should. i.e. keep going back to my 'ActiveSheet' to create a 'New Invoice'. My original code worked perfectly prior to this.

Comment: I am trying to account for other users using this workbook. Again @Dominque, thank you for your help. Still researching....